# how to find the sum that is less than 1000 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I am trying to find the sum of sales which is less than `1000` with the following query and I am mentioning the error message also.
would greatly appreciate the help.

```
SELECT 
    DELI_DT,
    BILL_NO,br_cd,
    Prod,
    ROUND(SUM(SALE),2)<1000 SALE
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DELI_DT,
        b.BILL_NO,
        b.br_cd,
        b.CAT_CD||b.PRD_CD Prod,
        nvl(SUM(b.sale_net),0)-nvl(sum(RT_QTY*FLAT_RT),0) SALE
    from BILL_DET b, BILL_MAS a
    here a.BILL_NO = b.BILL_NO
    AND a.SC_CD = b.SC_CD
    and b.TYP_CD='09'
    and  a.SALE_CD NOT IN ('RS','IN','EX')
    AND DELI_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-15' and '02-JUL-15'
    GROUP BY Deli_DT,b.BILL_NO,b.br_cd,b.CAT_CD||b.PRD_CD
)
group by DELI_DT,BILL_NO,br_cd,Prod,SALE
ORDER BY 1
```

Error message :

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: change the here to where and try once. this is the line "here a.BILL_NO = b.BILL_NO"

Comment: what is here in your code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the modification of your query

```
 SELECT DELI_DT,BILL_NO,br_cd,Prod, SALE
 FROM
    (SELECT DELI_DT,b.BILL_NO,b.br_cd,b.CAT_CD||b.PRD_CD Prod,nvl(SUM(b.sale_net),0)-nvl(sum(RT_QTY*FLAT_RT),0) SALE
    from BILL_DET b join 
    BILL_MAS a
    on
    a.BILL_NO = b.BILL_NO
    AND a.SC_CD = b.SC_CD
    and   b.TYP_CD='09'
    and  a.SALE_CD NOT IN ('RS','IN','EX')
    AND DELI_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-15' and '02-JUL-15'
    GROUP BY Deli_DT,b.BILL_NO,b.br_cd,b.CAT_CD||b.PRD_CD
    )
 GROUP BY DELI_DT,BILL_NO,br_cd,Prod,SALE
 HAVING ROUND(SUM(SALE),2)<1000
 ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
SELECT 
    DELI_DT,
    BILL_NO,br_cd,
    Prod,
    ROUND(SUM(SALE),2)<1000 SALE
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DELI_DT,
        b.BILL_NO,
        b.br_cd,
        b.CAT_CD||b.PRD_CD Prod,
        nvl(SUM(b.sale_net),0)-nvl(sum(RT_QTY*FLAT_RT),0) SALE
    from BILL_DET b
    join BILL_MAS a 
        on a.BILL_NO = b.BILL_NO
        AND a.SC_CD = b.SC_CD
    where b.TYP_CD='09'
    and  a.SALE_CD NOT IN ('RS','IN','EX')
    AND DELI_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-15' and '02-JUL-15'
    GROUP BY Deli_DT,b.BILL_NO,b.br_cd,b.CAT_CD||b.PRD_CD
)
group by DELI_DT,BILL_NO,br_cd,Prod,SALE
ORDER BY 1
```